# Desktop won't display correctly

Tags: 12.04, graphics

I recently installed 12.04 LTS.  However, the the graphical desktop is "broken" (it seems that the screen drawing is failing, fading and flashing each of the "triangles" created on the screen). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the system several times and this did not work. Is there something that can fix this?

*untranslated original:
ola pessoal, sou uruario linux a 1 ano, recentemente instalei no pc o linux ubuntu 12.04 lts precise pangolin mas ele fica com a interface grafica "quebrada" (parece que a tela foi dividida de ponta a ponta e fica falhando, sumindo e piscando em cada um dos "triangulos" criados na tela) eu gostaria de saber como posso resolver este problema, pois ja tentei desintalar e reinstalar o sistema varias vezes e nao funcionou(ja ate baixar a versao de outros sites mas deu na mesma) existe algo a ser feito ou devo usar o windows mesmo?*

Answer (score 0):

You may try to install video drivers for your system. In a terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get install flgrx
```

if you have an ATI card, or

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

if you have an Nvidia graphics card.

If this fails, try logging in with Ubuntu 2D(On the login window, click the gear icon, and pick Ubuntu 2D), or try using LDXE(`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` in the terminal)

If you don't know what to do with the commands above, you may press CTRL+ALT+T and then type the command(Or paste with `right-click`>`PASTE` as Terminal uses `Ctrl+V` for something else)